# A question about the size of reduced Groebner basis

Tags: commutative-algebra, groebner-basis

Let $I=(f,g,h)$ be an ideal in the polynomial ring $k[x,y,z]$ with $LT(f)>LT(g)>LT(h)$ in the lexorder, and $I$ is "reduced" in the sense that $LT(g)\nmid LT(f),LT(h)\nmid LT(g),LT(h)\nmid LT(f)$. Is it necessary that the reduced Groebner basis $G$ of $I$ has at least $3$ elements?

**Edit:** We may restrict to the nontrivial case.

Comment: exercise 15 on P332 of Dummit&Foote' ABSTRACT ALGEBRA shows that the leading terms of a minimal Groebner basis and the number of elemtents in any two minimal Groebner basis are unique.So the answer is yes.

Comment: How do you know that $f,g,h$ is a Grobner basis for $I$?

Comment: If the ordering you mentioned is strictly greater, then do you imply that $LT(f),LT(g),LT(h)$ are coprime with each other? In that case $G$ is just $\{f,g,h\}$ itself. Because while running the buchberger's algorithm, $S-poly(f,g) \rightarrow_{\{f,g\}} 0$ wherever $LT(f),LT(g)$ are co-prime. Hence all S-polynomials will reduce to zero in the first iteration itself. So Groebner basis comes out as the initial set itself. And this is indeed the reduced basis.

Comment: The ordering is not necessarily "strictly greater".For example,$x^3yz>xy^2z^3>y^3z$.I think user26857's doubt in his comment is reasonable,I can't convince myself now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to your question is no. Consider the following polynomials;
$$f=x^3y+x^2y^2,\quad g=x^2y^2+xy^3,\quad h=xy^3+xy.$$
In lexicographic order with $x>y>z$, we have $f,g,h\in k[x,y]\subset k[x,y,z]$ and $LT(f)=x^3y$, $LT(g)=x^2y^2$, $LT(h)=xy^3$. Therefore $LT(f)\gneq LT(g)\gneq LT(h)$ and none of these three leading terms divides another. However the reduced Grobner basis of $\langle f,g,h\rangle$ in this monomial order is $\{xy^3+xy,x^2y+xy^2\}$ which has 2 (less than 3) elements.